# zcat or gzip -dc taking more time while searching the string in 48364 files

Tags: gzip, zcat

**scripts:**

for file in `find /var/opt/Delivered -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*202402*"`
do
awk -F"," ' NR>1 {OFS="|";print $7,$6}' <(gzip -dc $file) >> 2.txt
done

Please let me know if any changes requires to make it faster in the above scripts